# Persian standard keyboard there isn't in Ubuntu 22.04 keyboard layouts

Tags: 22.04, keyboard-layout, internationalization

Recently I installed the latest version of Ubuntu 22.04, in previous version I cloud easily  add it.
settings > keyboard > click on + > Persian standard keyboard.

But in this version of Ubuntu I have just Persian item, this layout is not standard.

Comment: I don't see any variant named "Persian standard keyboard". The variant "Persian" is the standard AFAICT. Please clarify.

Comment: We have two types of layout in Farsi, the standard layout has a small difference with the other one in the type of characters, there is no standard keyboard in this Persian layout. @GunnarHjalmarsson

Comment: The source of the 22.04 Persian layouts is in [this file](https://salsa.debian.org/xorg-team/data/xkeyboard-config/-/blob/63d28e7a62aa27c2c31872c3f37cf1297e2ba630/symbols/ir). Can you please be specific about what the problem is? Is it possibly something which has been fixed [later](https://salsa.debian.org/xorg-team/data/xkeyboard-config/-/blob/debian-unstable/symbols/ir)?

Comment: Thank you man. It didn't work at first but currently it's work fine. very strange. @GunnarHjalmarsson